# Run python script from a button on html

Tags: python, html, button

I have a python scrip that I would like to run whenever a button in pressed on an html file. I have checked other questions on here but most are either php or some other type of language. I would just like to use html. 
Here is the html I tired so far

```
<html>
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='C:\Reporting\run_me.py'('Report Running')">Sensor Report</button>
<html>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are planning on serving this file on the internet, href will not always be `C:\`. That is on your local machine. You will want to move the python script somewhere more accessible.

Comment: This is going to stay local in our environment and not on the internet.